# FilterList with a SelectItem FilterItem

Tags: react-admin

I have what is probably a common situation. In many of my applications `<List>` pages I have a Filter aside. Wonderful from a UIX standpoint on wide displays.

The `<FilterList>` component generally works great when the number of  children is fairly limited/coarse grained. It is also not an appropriate when the filter item is fine grained (e.g. >7).

When the filter is somewhere in the middle (e.g., >5 and <50) is there a mechanism to use a `<SelectItem>` instead of the `<FilterListItem>`...`<FilterListItem>` pattern?

Having a long list of `<FilterListItem>` is not tenable from UIX perspective.

Example of typical use-case where 'Level' is 4-6 values:

```
   <FilterList label="Event Level" icon={<InfoIcon />}>
       {validLevels}
   </FilterList>
```

Example of common use-case where the number of **Sources** is ~>7 leads to a long list of items in the aside:

```
   <FilterList label="Source" icon={<SourceIcon />}>
       {sourceList}
   </FilterList>
```

How could I do something like this?

```
   <FilterList label="Source" icon={<SourceIcon />}>
       <SelectInput source="sourceCode" choices={validSourceList}/>
   </FilterList>
```

Obviously it's missing the **binding** between the value chosen from the validSourceList and the **value** aspect of a  component.

Certainly someone has done this... And maybe it's even on the roadmap for RA.

FWIW, I'd be happy to pay someone to write this if it doesn't exist and won't appear in RA anytime soon.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's a common use-case or not (but if it is, it would definitely be a good idea to create an easier solution directly in react-admin to address it), but in any case it is a good question.

There are probably several ways to do this, but here's what I would do.

First I would leverage [`<FilterForm>`](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/FilterForm.html) to create a custom filter form, where I can use react-admin input components such as `<TextInput>` or `<SelectInput>`. Remember to put the `alwaysOn` prop on them to have them show up without a [`<FilterButton>`](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/FilteringTutorial.html#the-filter-buttonform-combo).

Then I would use a [`<SelectInput>`](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/SelectInput.html#choices) with a list of `choices` and a `format` and a `parse` prop to actually turn them into what I want (a range in this example).

```
      <FilterForm
        filters={[
          <SelectInput
            alwaysOn
            source="views"
            choices={[
              { id: 0, name: '0 - 100' },
              { id: 1, name: '100 - 200' },
              { id: 2, name: '200 - 300' },
              { id: 3, name: '> 300' },
            ]}
            parse={(id) => {
              switch (id) {
                case 1:
                  return { views_gt: 100, views_lte: 200 };
                case 2:
                  return { views_gt: 200, views_lte: 300 };
                case 3:
                  return { views_gt: 300 };
                default:
                  return { views_lte: 100 };
              }
            }}
            format={(value) => {
              switch (value?.views_gt) {
                case 100:
                  return 1;
                case 200:
                  return 2;
                case 300:
                  return 3;
                default:
                  return 0;
              }
            }}
          />,
        ]}
      />
```

Currently this will return filters like:

```js
filter: {
  views: {
    views_gt: 100,
    views_lte: 200
  }
}
```

So we need a final ingredient, in the `dataProvider`, to transform the filter to a format our API will understand. I choose to leverage [`withLifecycleCallbacks`](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/withLifecycleCallbacks.html) to do that:

```
const dataProvider = withLifecycleCallbacks(fakeRestProvider(data, true), [
  {
    resource: 'posts',
    beforeGetList: async (params) => {
      const {
        filter: { views, ...otherFilters },
        ...rest
      } = params;
      return {
        ...rest,
        filter: {
          ...otherFilters,
          ...views,
        },
      };
    },
  },
]);
```

Now our filter looks like this, which is what we want:

```js
filter: {
    views_gt: 100,
    views_lte: 200
}
```

You can find a complete example in this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-bqhhct?file=src%2Fposts%2FPostList.tsx)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Very helpful. Thx. Cleanly `<FilterForm>` has the capability already. Maybe the `<SelectInput>` will migrate to the `<FilterList>` at some point. 

I can see that RA has a bit of a conundrum: they have the 'Filters on top' and 'Filters on the side' choices -- and some gaps in the capabilities between them.  Tricky.